# How to get value of Json field value from a .NET COM visible dll in VB6.0

Tags: c#, json, types, vb6, legacy

I have a C# COM visible DLL that works with web services. That COM visible DLL is being referenced and used in a VB6 application. The COM visible DLL has a function that pulls data from a web service call and gets the data in Json format, and then it also de-serializes the Json document to a class object, and returns the object id field (string type) from the function. The VB6 app calls that function and tries to get the id value. But it does not retrieve the value. The same COM Dll and same function is used in a .NET app. (C#), then the id field value can be retrieved.

How to get the correct value in VB 6 ? Highly Appreciate your response.

COM Dll function Code:

```
public string TestGETTransactionId(string transaction_id, ref string exceptionMessage)
        {
            exceptionMessage = "";
            string sReturnString = " - 9999";

            try
            {
                string sDomain = HostUrl;
                string sNamespace = Namespace;
                string sLocationId = LocationID;
                string sDeveloperId = DeveloperID;
                string sUserId = UserId;
                string sUserAPIKey = UserApiId;
                string sUserHashKey = UserHashKey;
                string sEndPoint = TransactionsRetail;

                //query to see if it is Okay...                
                sEndPoint = "transactions";
                string sUrl = sDomain + @"/" + sNamespace + @"/" + sEndPoint + "?transaction_id=" + transaction_id;              
                var client = new RestClient(sUrl);                
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("user-id", sUserId);
                request.AddHeader("user-api-key", sUserAPIKey);
                request.AddHeader("developer-id", sDeveloperId);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
              

                TransactionRetail_Rootobject transactionRetail_Rootobject = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<TransactionRetail_Rootobject>(response.Content);              

                if (transactionRetail_Rootobject.transactions != null)
                {
                    sReturnString = transactionRetail_Rootobject.transactions[0].id.ToString();
                }         

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {              
                exceptionMessage = ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException;
            }
            return sReturnString; 

     }

VB6 Caller:

    Dim sTransaction_api_id As String    
    Dim sExceptionMesg As String
    Dim sReturnedId As String
'
    sTransaction_api_id = "SAMINC_transID001"  ' change this to try
    
    sReturnedId = MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass(sTransaction_api_id, sExceptionMesg)
    
    MsgBox sReturnedId    'This always return the error code -9999 and I expect to get the true ID field value
    
    MsgBox sExceptionMesg

C# Caller:

        private void btnTestGetTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sTransaction_id = "SAMINC_transID001";
            string sExceptionMesg = "";
           
            MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass obj = new MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass();

            string sResult = obj.TestGETTransactionId(sTransaction_id, ref sExceptionMesg);

            MessageBox.Show(sResult); // this returns the ID field value fine

            textBox1.Text = sResult;

        }
```

Comment: Is it the ref string exceptionMessage? What if you return the error itself? So: return  ex.Message.ToString(); (in the exception) ? That would give you more information. Looking at the code, I suspect that the .net has an error. It could be higher up, so the ref won't get filled and you will not see it. I have experience with VB6 for 20 yrs and .net over 10. Also COM and SOAP with .NET and VB6. Let me know what you need.

Comment: The .NET caller has no error whatsoever. I can get the ID value in .NET caller. 

The problem is in the line

TransactionRetail_Rootobject transactionRetail_Rootobject = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<TransactionRetail_Rootobject>(response.Content);

VB6 caller can not execute this line and error out. "SimpleJson" is a static class from  RestSharp. Just to call a Json deserializer to parse the Json document to a class object, so I can retrieve the field ID value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

What happened was I had to use a different way to make web services call. I use WinHttp reference in .NET to create routines for web services calls, instead of using RestClient.  WinHttp provides more transparency to communicate with VB 6. The caller from VB 6 and C# do not need to change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some differences in the VB6 and C# code you provided.

Namely, you are calling different constructor in VB6:

```
sReturnedId = MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass(sTransaction_api_id, sExceptionMesg)
```

compared to the C# version:

```
MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass obj = new MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass();
```

on which then you call the `TestGETTransactionId` method:

```
string sResult = obj.TestGETTransactionId(sTransaction_id, ref sExceptionMesg);
```

Try the following:

```
obj = MyCOMDLL.MyComDllClass()

sResult = obj.TestGETTransactionId(sTransaction_api_id, sExceptionMesg)

MessageBox sResult
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the code in an IDE.

Comment: Thanks for response. It is not the issue from the Caller. COM dll is using RestSharp to work with Json. I don't know if anything needs to do on RestSharp.

Comment: If you can modify the C# service, try isolating the issue by splitting the code on chunks and return dummy data which you can validate at your VB side. You can also try using different JSON deserializers like Newtonsoft.JSON instead of the one provided by RestSharp and see if that works for you. Let me know what you'll find out.

Comment: Do you get the same error with the sample code provided in the answer? Your VB code should mimic the C# one as close as possible. Can you post the full code from the COM service constructors?